# Physical meaning of the WZW action and Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, conformal-field-theory, affine-lie-algebra, wess-zumino-witten

What is the (super)-WZW term physical meaning? I mean, what is the physical importance of the [Wess-Zumino-Witten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wess%E2%80%93Zumino%E2%80%93Witten_model) action/Lagrangian in superstrings/M-theory and or field theory (not stringy if available).